Largest collections of subsets
I need to find largest collection of subsets of $\{1,\ldots, 84\}$ such that each subset has size 5 and any two distinct subsets have exactly one element in common.
Any help is appreciated, Thanks

Because each pair appears in at most one subset, an upper bound is $\lfloor \binom{84}{2}/\binom{5}{2} \rfloor = 348$.

I have an intuition that the answer is just $20$, with the simple construction of ${1,2,3,4,5},{1,6,7,8,9},\dots,{1,78,79,80,81}$; because if we have even a single group with the common element not present, we would constrict ouselves to less than that. I'll try to prove this when I get time.

The largest such collection has $21$ sets. We can do this using only the first $21$ numbers, $\{1,\dots,21\}$. Specifically, we use the finite projective plane of order $4$ on this set. A particular way to do this is given in the La Jolla covering repository, with parameters $(v,k,t)=(21,5,2)$.
https://ljcr.dmgordon.org/cover/show_cover.php?v=21&k=5&t=2

1  2  5 15 17      2  3  6 16 18      3  4  7 17 19  
4  5  8 18 20      5  6  9 19 21      1  6  7 10 20  
2  7  8 11 21      1  3  8  9 12      2  4  9 10 13  
3  5 10 11 14      4  6 11 12 15      5  7 12 13 16  
6  8 13 14 17      7  9 14 15 18      8 10 15 16 19  
9 11 16 17 20     10 12 17 18 21      1 11 13 18 19  
2 12 14 19 20      3 13 15 20 21      1  4 14 16 21


I will now prove that this is optimal. First of all, we can rule out the trivial configuration where there is some number that appears in all of the subsets. Say all sets contain the number $1$. If you removed $1$ from all subsets, you would be left with several disjoint subsets of $\{2,3,\dots,84\}$, so there is only enough room for $\lfloor 83/4\rfloor=20$ such subsets.
For all nontrivial configurations, we can prove that each number in $\{1,\dots,84\}$ appears in at most $5$ sets. Let $x$ be any number in $\{1,\dots,84\}$. Since the collection is nontrivial, we know that not all of the subsets contain $x$, so there exists some subset $S$ which does not contain $x$. Now, for each subset $T$ which contains $x$, we know that $T\cap S$ has one element. Furthermore, for any two subsets $T_1$ and $T_2$ both containing $x$, the unique elements of $T_1\cap S$ and $T_2 \cap S$ must be distinct. Indeed, if $T_1\cap S=T_2\cap S=\{y\}$, then $T_1\cap T_2$ would contain $\{x,y\}$, contradicting $|T_1\cap T_2|=1$. Since there are only five elements of $S$ available, there can only be $5$ sets containing $x$.
Finally, let $R$ be some subset in the collection, containing numbers $\{r_1,r_2,r_3,r_4,r_5\}$. Note that every other set in the collection except for $R$ must contain exactly one of $r_1,\dots,r_5$. Furthermore, for each $i\in \{1,\dots,5\}$, there are at most $4$ sets (besides $R$) containing $r_i$, because we know there are at most five sets total containing $r_i$. Therefore, the total number of sets is at most
$$
1+5\cdot 4=21.
$$
